# post parameter 'name' 404 error

Tags: 404-error

I am integrating the WorldPay hosted payment pages gateway to my WordPress installation and I am setting a notification URL in WorldPay to a route within WordPress.

The problem I am having is that WordPress automatically responds with a 404 error if you pass it a parameter called 'name', or any other reserved term as defined here: [WordPress reserved Terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms) as WorldPay does.

I was wondering whether it is possible to change this default 404 response, I have tried using `unset($_POST['name'])` within my plugin code, but I assume that this is too late within the request lifecycle as it didn't alter the response. I would also prefer not to set my callback url to another script, which would then alter the $_POST array and pass it on to my plugin, if anyone can suggest a way I can achieve a 200 response without doing this?

**edit: My question in a much easier to read format**

Remote service X is sending a callback to my WordPress site of example.com/?name=nameofaccount how do you handle that when WordPress uses name as a reserved term and the remote service wont change?

Comment: Please show your complete code. From reading your question it is quite unclear what you are actually asking.

Comment: My code is of no relevance unfortunately, as the post back to my website is initiated by WorldPay - I wish to be able to handle a post request that contains a parameter called 'name', if that is alittle more succint for you?

Comment: I read it as: Remote service X is sending a callback to my WordPress site of example.com/?name=nameofaccount how do you handle that when WordPress uses name as a reserved term and the remote service wont change?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as though WorldPay is responsible for sending the overly generic `name` parameter so you aren't in a position to control that. You will instead have to catch the request and force it to work. Something like:

```
function redir_404_wpse_137703() {
  if (is_404() && isset($_GET['name'])) {
    locate_template('some-theme-template.php',true);
    exit;
  }
}
add_action('template_redirect','redir_404_wpse_137703');
```

`some-theme-template.php` will need to be constructed with `get_header()`, content,  and `get_footer()` like normal custom templates.

The big problem I see is sorting out genuine 404s from WorldPay ones but there must be other parameters that would help sort that out.

Comment: Thanks for this, and sorry for the lack of clarity in my initial question, but I would like to actually modify the HTTP status code that is returned, i.e. return a 200 response, as it is the http status code is what is causing WorldPay to disregard the response body

Comment: You need WorldPay to request your page?

Comment: WorldPay sends a transaction notifcation to a URL I define in WorldPay, this notification is in the form of a POST request, one of the parameters of this POST request is 'name' which WordPress detects and automatically returns a 404 response. I would like to be able to bypass WordPress's detection of this parameter, or change the response if possible.

Comment: Why not just use a subdomain for the World Pay Request and use a simple PHP script to manage the response and then move to the page you need with in wordpress?